# numpy: issues with indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having some issue where I sort a numpy array and get the indexes for the sorting array but applying the index to the original array does not do what I expected. So, here is a test case for what I am doing:

```
 import numpy as np

 # Two 3x3 matrices
 x = np.random.rand(2, 3, 3)
 # Perform some decomposition (Never mind the matrices are not hermitian...) 
 evals, evecs = np.linalg.eigh(x)

 # evals has shape (2, 3), evecs has shape (2, 3, 3)
 indices = evals.argsort(axis=1)[..., ::-1] # Do descending sort

 # Now I want to apply the index to evals.
 evals = evals[:, indices]
```

Instead of getting back a (2, 3) array, I am getting a (2, 3, 3) array back where the rows are getting replicated. Something like:

```
array([[[ 1.15628047,  0.16853886, -0.28607138],
        [ 1.15628047,  0.16853886, -0.28607138]],

       [[ 2.4311532 , -0.00754817, -0.24086572],
        [ 2.4311532 , -0.00754817, -0.24086572]]])
```

I am not sure why that is. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: `evals[:, index]` return the `index`'th column of your array that is `array([ 1.2101455 ,  1.42952306])` so what you expect ?

Comment: Well, I was expecting permutation according to index. Well, first I had tried evals[index] which did not work too. The result I was expecting was:
array([[[ 1.15628047,  0.16853886, -0.28607138]],
       [[ 2.4311532 , -0.00754817, -0.24086572]]])

Comment: You are getting back a `(2,2,3)`.  The 1st 2 is 1st dim of `evals`, the `(2,3)` comes from indexing the last dim of `evals` with a (2,3) array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
idx0 = np.arange(evals.shape[0])[:,np.newaxis]
idx1 = evals.argsort(1)[...,::-1]
evals[idx0,idx1]
```

This sorts each row, individually, by decreasing order.

EDIT:
In this case you need the `(idx0,idx1)` to further process the eigenvectors  `evecs`. If this wasn't the case, it is straightforward to do

```
evals.sort()
evals = evals[:,::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks. What is this newaxis? I just tried to run it with ipython and it barfed at that....
Never mind...np.newaxis

Comment: You need that to transform a 1D array with shape `(X,)` like `[0,1,2]` into a 2D "column" array with shape `(X,1)`, i.e. `[[0],[1],[2]]`.

Comment: This did the job! Would you mind elaborating on this line? idx0 = np.arange(evals.shape[0])[:,np.newaxis]

Comment: that creates a column array with all indices from `0` to the length-1 of the array in the first dimension, which is `evals.shape[0]`.